# Being Y a standard normal random variable and X an independent Bernoulli random variable, what is the characteristic function of YX?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

$$Y \sim N(0,1) $$

$$ X \sim b\left(\frac 1 2\right)$$

Knowing that $Y$ and $X$ are independent, how do I compute the characteristic function of $YX$? What do I have to expect? A function that depends on a scalar $t$ or a vector $(t_1,t_2)$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A binomial depends on 2 variables, a probability and a sample size. Do you mean a Bernoulli?

Comment: I'm sorry I clearly meant Bernoulli, fixed it

Comment: Condition on $X$ since it's discrete

Comment: To answer your specific question, YX is a single scalar random variable so its characteristic function takes a scalar $t$ and returns a scalar $E[e^{itYX}]$. As for how to compute it, you just condition on $X$, which is easy to do because it is discrete and independent of $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
E[\exp(itXY)] &= E[\exp(itXY) \mid X = 0] P(X = 0) \\
&+ E[\exp(itXY) \mid X = 1] P(X = 1) \\
&= E[1 \mid X=0] \frac12 + E[\exp(itY)] \frac12 \tag{$X \sim Ber(1/2)$} \\
&= \frac12\left( 1+\exp\left(-\frac12 t^2\right) \right)
\tag{$Y \sim N(0,1)$}
\end{align}